# how good is "Chrome Password Checkup" extension for checking passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-management

From what I read so far Google "Chrome Password Checkup" extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/password-checkup/pncabnpcffmalkkjpajodfhijclecjno) checking the password that you use for login (regardless it saved in chrome or not) with known data breaches databases that available online.
based on google explanation it's also used for google services passwords even without "Chrome Password Checkup" extensions. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/9231944

Interesting how good is this password checker?
so far (used it for 1 week) it only warn me about some test accounts that I used locally with really known password like test123

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? This extension literally checks passwords against a list of passwords Google already knows have been leaked in the past. It does exactly that and no more; it won't look for passwords that are weak in some other way. What exactly are you expecting it to do differently?

Comment: @Ben well, it's more general question. I don't think Google is publishing somewhere the sources and algorithms that used for cheeking if password exposed for security reason. Also probably google consistently working on improving the extension but I seen couple of comments that some passwords that displayed as pwned in sites like https://haveibeenpwned.com/ but not alerted by "Chrome password checkup". so, rephrasing the question: how good is "Chrome password checker " comparing to other similar programs like  https://haveibeenpwned.com/ or "dark web" checking credit report subscriptions etc.

Comment: I understand that  "Chrome password checkup" was released less than month ago and probably not much research done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** Google Chrome Password Check-up fares worse compared to the likes of HIBP, Firefox Monitor, etc...

---

Note: The extension in the question which checks logins against known data breaches is now deprecated and the feature is now part of Google Chrome.

Now answering your question, "*how good is "Chrome password checker "comparing to other similar programs like haveibeenpwned.com or "dark web" checking credit report subscriptions etc.*". Google Chrome Password Check-up fares worse compared to the likes of HIBP, Firefox Monitor, etc... Here's why I came to that conclusion

**Google checks for a combination of username & password**

Unlike HIBP, Google does not alert you when only your password is breached. From [Google's blog post](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/02/protect-your-accounts-from-data.html),

> We won’t bother you about outdated passwords you’ve already reset or
> merely weak passwords like “123456”. We only generate an alert when
> both your current username and password appear in a breach, as that
> poses the greatest risk.

Not alerting you to change a password like "123456" just because your email/username has not yet appeared on a breach is not at all good.

**No information on non-password data breaches**

From the [Google security blog](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/02/protect-your-accounts-from-data.html),

> While it’s possible for data breaches to expose other personal data
> such as a phone number or mailing address, there’s no straightforward
> next step to re-securing that data. That’s why we focus only on
> warning you about unsafe usernames and passwords.

I would still like me to know about data breaches of my account even is the password or hash is not leaked.